# Laravel 5.6 - Timeout error after framework update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, axios

Two days ago I started to experiencing a strange issue.

I just launched a `composer update` on my current *Laravel 5.6* project.

After that, all my `ajax` calls to the project API,  done via `axios` from a `Vue` component, aren't working anymore.

No **crud** operations are being executed, and the process seems to be interrupted before the task starts.

Any call throws this exception after a long timeout:

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

This is a `500` error, and the file involved it has been identified as `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php`.

Any idea on what is causing this problem?

I'm not sure where to check in particular, so if it could be useful, tell me what can I share from source and I'll proper update the question.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Check your server error logs and laravel logs to see if there's any information there.

Comment: Create an ajax test call where no database interactions are done, just static json as a reply. It seems odd the database connection is the culprit. Try the call in both web.php and api.php. I'm really curious what the reason of your issue is.

Comment: Hi @dimitri I tried to set up that scenario but for me it's impossible to verify it, because I just noticed that for unkown reason laravel isn't compiling my components anymore! Edits aren't being recompiled so the output still the same (of course browser cache is disabled).

Comment: Update: I solved the compiling problem. Now, with a test call everything works - controllers respond to request, data being fetced. it seems related to DB operations. So Laravel update doesn't matter. I could try to think that it depends to my MAMP config but this issue started before my updating to version 5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @migser from *Slack* official channel, I found the cause.

No update of any sort ruined my stack, but a bad use of `touches` array inside both two `hasMany` related models were freezing the called tasks.

By removing the wrong `touches` declaration - the one present inside model with relation declaration - all crud tasks works fine again.

Thanks everyone for the tips and help.

Answer (score 0):

Try modify your `php.ini` and add this:

`ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`

or

In your `.htaccess`

`php_value max_execution_time 300`

then:

```
composer dump-autoload

php artisan cache:clear
```

Finally, you should test it again.

Comment: Thanks @henry but nothing changed for now. However I'm still investigating.

Comment: With ```max_execution_time 300``` nothing happens: no action, no exception neither.

Comment: Increasing maximum execution time is generally a bad idea, unless you're dealing with intentionally long running command line scripts. It doesn't fix the problem, nor does it help find it.